# Flexforms in extension without plugin

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a extbase extension which inserts a content element over PageTSconfig:

`NewContentElementWizard.ts`:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common {
        elements {
                tz_linkrow {
                    iconIdentifier = content-textpic
                    title = LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db_new_content_el.xlf:wizards.newContentElement.myext_title
                    description = LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db_new_content_el.xlf:wizards.newContentElement.myext_description
                    tt_content_defValues {
                        CType = myext_linkrow
                    }
                }
        }
        show := addToList(linkrow)
    }
```

Is there a possibility to use a flexform?
How can i insert it`?

Comment: you want to prefill the flexforms by get arguments or you want to add flexforms to the content element?

Comment: i want to add flexforms to the content element

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
        $_EXTKEY,
        'FILE:EXT:pf_spacer/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_ds.xml',
        'tz_linkrow'
    );

    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'pi_flexform', 'myext_linkrow', 'replace:rowDescription');
```